# React needs to be handled some if conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with the if statement. The problem is I need to create a condition if the array has 2 object needs to be true if has 1 object it should be false. the objects are strings please check the code.

```
    const { program } = useContext(ProgramContext);
    const { authMethods } = program;

    let loginComponent;
    let claimComponent;
    let insertRow;
    let insertEnd;
    if (authMethods) {
        if (authMethods.indexOf('login') !== -1) {
            loginComponent = (
                <div className="col-md-6 d-flex">
                    <div className="card flex-grow-1 mb-md-0">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h3 className="card-title">Login</h3>
                            <form>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="login-id">User ID</label>
                                    <input
                                        id="login-id"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Please enter user ID"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="login-password">Password</label>
                                    <input
                                        id="login-password"
                                        type="password"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Password"
                                    />
                                    <small className="form-text text-muted">
                                        <ErrModal />
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <div className="form-check">
                                        <span className="form-check-input input-check">
                                            <span className="input-check__body">
                                                <input
                                                    id="login-remember"
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    className="input-check__input"
                                                />
                                                <span className="input-check__box" />
                                                <Check9x7Svg className="input-check__icon" />
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="login-remember">
                                            Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary mt-2 mt-md-3 mt-lg-4">
                                    Login
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
        if (authMethods.indexOf('claim') !== -1) {
            claimComponent = (
                <div className="col-md-6 d-flex mt-4 mt-md-0">
                    <div className="card flex-grow-1 mb-0">
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h3 className="card-title">Claim</h3>
                            <form>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label htmlFor="claim-code">Enter Claim Code</label>
                                    <input
                                        id="register-email"
                                        type="text"
                                        className="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Claim Code"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" style={{ marginTop: '186px' }}>
                                    Claim
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    console.log(loginComponent);
    console.log(claimComponent);
const rowComponent = (
    <div className="container">
        {insertRow}
        {loginComponent}
        {claimComponent}
        {insertEnd}
    </div>
);
```

Basically I want to add row class if there are 2 items in the array otherwise I don't need a row.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear so I'll chalk out a similar example:

```
import React from 'react'

const Component = () => {
    const arr = ["foo", "bar"];
    const rowClass = arr.length === 2 ? "row" : "";

    return (
        <div className={rowClass}>
            This is an example
        </div>
    )
}

export default Component
```